# Unable to iterate over the src tags using XElement in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML of the following structure.

```
<DataElements>
  <source> <...Information goes here...></source>
    <destination> <......information goes here....</destination>
    <destination> <......information goes here....</destination>
    <destination> <......information goes here....</destination>
<DataElements>
```

I am using foreach to iterate over each subelement in the XML.
I am able to iterate over the **source** tag and unable to understand how to iterate over **all** of the **destination** tags.

I have placed the piece of code below. Please guide me on how to resolve this issue.

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Elements(Elements.DataElements))
{
    //code goes here
  foreach (XElement subelement in    
  element.Elements(Elements.Destination))  --> i seem to iterate only on the first destination tag rather than all of them
  {

  }

}
```

The Destination refers to string "destination" and the DataElements to string "DataElements".

Comment: Please update your question with valid xml example and place exact strings passed as parameters, instead of `Elements.` constants.

Comment: @Reniuz just made the chagnes

Comment: I don't know how it works for you, but with example it doesn't iterate in first foreach loop. What you want is `doc.Root.Elements("destination")`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided, you will simply need to do the following:

```
foreach (XElement destinationElement in doc.Root.Elements("destination"))
{
     // This will loop through all child elements named 'destination'
}
```

I'm assuming Elements.Destination == "destination".